# How can I get rid of this extra level when pushing objects to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I am using Jquery to read a JSON file and am filtering select items from that file into a new array.

The JSON file looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1234",
    "label": "Product 1",
    "price": "140"
  },
  {
    "id": "5678",
    "label": "Product 2",
    "price": "199"
  },
  {
    "id": "9012",
    "label": "Product 3",
    "price": "500"
  },
  // etc
]
```

I am using the following code to retrieve the data I want:

```
const activeProdIDs = [
  1234,
  9012
];

let filteredJson = [];

 $.ajax({
        url: dataURL,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (myJson) {
            
            activeProdIDs.forEach(function(prodID) {
                filteredJson.push(myJson.filter(item => item.id == prodID));
            });

            console.log(filteredJson);

    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("Something went wrong");
    },
});
```

And this works, but the array that is returned has an extra level/layer to it:

```
[
    [
        {
        "id": "1234",
        "label": "Product 1",
        "price": "140"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
        "id": "9012",
        "label": "Product 3",
        "price": "500"
        }
    ],
    //etc
]
```

So instead of accessing a product's label like `filteredJson[0].label` I must do `filteredJson[0][0].label`.

Would anyone know why the filter is pushing the JSON objects as their own array ane what I could do to fix this?

(This also seems to happen if I add the JSON objects to another object instead of an array).

Comment: `let filtered = myJson.filter(el => activeProdIds.includes(el.id))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array where you're only looking for single elements.

You could use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead but I would suggest sticking with `filter()` and using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of IDs for more performant lookups

```js
const ids = new Set(activeProdIDs.map(String)); // match types
const filteredJson = myJson.filter(({ id }) => ids.has(id));
```

*Note:* this will return matching records in the order they appear in `myJson`. Your original code returns records in the order the IDs appear in `activeProdIDs` so if this is a problem, please make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use find function in this case:

```
filteredJson = activeProdIDs.map(id => myJson.find(item => item.id == id)).filter(item => item !== undefined)
```